# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Help me please, I want to CREATE PROCEDURE but I found error like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE studentAddOrEdit(
    IN _id INT,
    IN _firstname VARCHAR(191),
    IN _lastname VARCHAR(191)
)
BEGIN
IF _id = 0 THEN 
    INSERT INTO students(firstname, lastname) VALUES(_firstname,_lastname);
    SET  _id = LAST_INSERT_ID(); 
ELSE
    UPDATE
        students
    SET
        firstname = _firstname, lastname = _lastname
    WHERE
        id = _id;
END IF;
SELECT
    id AS _id
END
```

Now it says

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7

Comment: Which row is the problem row?

Comment: Why don't you just use [IODKU](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)?

Comment: And you seem to be requiring the CALLer to know whether the student already exists.  Use IODKU.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works when I add a few semicolons.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=61df1bbe0c5bdfcff55f4b534a43a00c) is an example.

You should probably have a `DELIMITER` statements as well, although that does not seem to work in db<>fiddle.